# MySQL: performing left joins with multiple conditions faster

Tags: mysql

I want to perform a left join in mySQL which will be performed on 4 different criteria:

```
select 
    a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
from 
    table1 as a
left join
    table2 as b on a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar 
                   or a.CommonVar= b.CommonVar2 
                   or a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar3 
                   or a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar4;
```

Unfortunately, this takes an unbelievable amount of time. Could anyone provide any ideas as to another way to perform this query which will produce the same results but at a vastly higher speed and lower time?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you set an index on **each column** `table1.CommonVar`, `table2.CommonVar`, `table2.CommonVar2`, `table2.CommonVar3` and `table2.CommonVar4` ?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but yes i have, unfortunately it did not help, it still takes alot of time to run the querry

Comment: Have you test this ?


SELECT a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.CommonVar IN (  b.CommonVar, b.CommonVar2, b.CommonVar3, b.CommonVar4);

Comment: how much entriesdo you have in the tables and what is your definition of "takes long"? What is the system like, how much memory do you have assigned to MySQL? Are you running on innodb or myisam?

Comment: What are the table structures? Why no explain plan? Is normalising the data an option? Why do you need to fetch all the matching rows? Why are you not using a materialised view? This is a very poor question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `IN()`:

```
select a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
from table1 as a
left join
table2 as b
WHERE a.CommonVar IN(b.CommonVar, b.CommonVar2, b.CommonVar3, b.CommonVar4);
```

Also I might suggest partitioning of the table if it has too many records.

Comment: can you add an explanation, why you think this should be faster?

Comment: @dognose At least because it does not have to fetch `a.CommonVar`  value four times (in `where`/`on` part).

Answer (score 0):

Are they indexed individually, or as a composite? Composite will not help you in this scenario. I am not sure if individually will in this kind of join either ( the query optimizer may not be designed to take advantage of them individually).

Worst case scenario, you could try this:

```
SELECT a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar
UNION
SELECT a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar2
UNION
SELECT a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar3
UNION
SELECT a.CommonVar, Var1, Var2, Var3
FROM table1 AS a 
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b
ON a.CommonVar = b.CommonVar4
;
```

Note will not give the exact same results. If a row in table1 has a match only on CommonVar, it will probably show up in results twice; once with match, and again without one. This may be resolvable by making this a subquery (*perhaps to something using GROUP_CONCAT() and grouping by a.CommonVar*).